# Equal row distance

Tags: tables, spacing

I am trying to indent text inside of a tabular using a `\parbox`.
Depending on the height of the `\parbox` the vertical distance to the next row varies. Also the vertical distance between the title and the content changes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\colwidth}{5cm}
\newcommand{\indentation}{1em}

\newcommand{\row}[2]{%
    \textbf{#1}\par
    \hspace*{\indentation}\parbox{\colwidth-\indentation}{#2}%
    \\[.5em]%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{\colwidth}}
\row{title}{short content}
\row{title}{content which is too long for one line}
\row{title}{short content again}
\row{title}{content which is too long for one line again}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why do the distances vary?
How can I make them constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `\parbox[t]`, but there's an easier method:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\colwidth}{5cm}
\newcommand{\indentation}{1em}

\newcommand{\row}[2]{%
  \hangindent=\indentation
  \hangafter=1
  \textbf{#1}\newline
  #2\\[.5em]
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{\colwidth}}
\row{title}{short content}
\row{title}{content which is too long for one line}
\row{title}{short content again}
\row{title}{content which is too long for one line again}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, set `\leftskip`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\colwidth}{5cm}
\newcommand{\indentation}{1em}

\newcommand{\row}[2]{%
  \leftskip=\indentation
  \hspace*{-\indentation}\textbf{#1}\newline
  #2\\[.5em]
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{\colwidth}}
\row{title}{short content}
\row{title}{content which is too long for one line}
\row{title}{short content again}
\row{title}{content which is too long for one line again}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than attempt `\parbox`es within `p` columns, I just let `p` be `p` as part of a 2-column table, and lapped the non-indent bolded stuff.

Note: indentation and colwidth bars are shown at the end to confirm that I adjusted `\tabcolsep` appropriately.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\colwidth}{5cm}
\newcommand{\indentation}{1em}

\tabcolsep=.5\dimexpr\indentation\relax
\newcommand{\row}[2]{%
    \rlap{\textbf{#1}}&\\
    &#2\\
}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}lp{\dimexpr\colwidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\row{title}{short content}
\row{title}{content which is too long for one line}
\row{title}{short content again}
\row{title}{content which is too long for one line again}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\noindent Indentation:\\
\noindent\rule{\indentation}{1pt}

\noindent Colwidth:\\
\noindent\rule{\colwidth}{1pt}
\end{document}
```

[image]